# Problema com Segmentation fault com ponteiro inteiro

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, memory-limit, falha-de-segmentação

O programa abaixo tenta reproduzir um modelo de autômato celular. Quando utilizo "n" (quantidade de células) acima de 65 mil, o programa retorna Segmentation fault.

Tentei "printar" algum texto em vários locais do código, porém não executa (o print) e já retorna Segmentation fault. O código segue abaixo e fico muito grato se puderem ajudar.

Obs: Meu único achismo sobre o que pode está ocorrendo de errado é que os ponteiros inteiros "p2" e "p3" não conseguem ser maiores que 65 mil.

Obs2: Caso queiram entender a fundo este modelo, ele se encontra descrito neste artigo: [Optimal Dynamical Range of Excitable Networks at Criticality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-bio/0601037.pdf)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


#define myrand ((float)(random())/(float)(RAND_MAX) ) 

const int   estados_maximos = 10,
            tempo = 1000,
            k = 10; //numero fixo de pos

const int n = 100000; //elementos

const float porcent = 0.1;

int n_ativados_inicial = ceil(porcent*n); //arredonda para mais

double sigma = 1.05;



int Existe(int valores[],int tam,int valor){
    for(int i = 0;i<tam;i++){
        if(valores[i]==valor)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void GeraAleatorios(int numeros[],int quantNumeros,int Limite,int elemento, int feliz){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL) + 5865*feliz); // pode-se somar algo para mudar a semente


    int v;
    for(int i=0;i<quantNumeros;i++){
        v = rand() % Limite;
        while(Existe(numeros,i,v) or v==elemento){
        v = rand() % Limite;
        //printf("preso %d ", v);
        rand();
        }
        numeros[i] = v;
    }

}

int main() {
    int i, j, t, aux, *p2, *p3;
    int pos[n][k], contemplados[n_ativados_inicial], estados1[n], estados2[n], total_ativos[tempo+1];
    double P[n][k], pmax, *p;
    FILE *rho;
    char name[100];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    pmax = (double)2*sigma/k;


    p2=&estados1[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){p2[i]=0;};

    //montar Pij
    p=P[0]; //apontar o ponteiro para o inicio de P
    for (i=0;i<n*k;i++)
    {p[i] = myrand*pmax;}

    GeraAleatorios(contemplados,n_ativados_inicial,n,n+10,1000);

    for(i=0; i<n_ativados_inicial; i++){estados1[contemplados[i]]=1;};
    total_ativos[0] = n_ativados_inicial;
    //gravar a quantidade de ativados inicialmente!
    t = 0;

    //arquivo
    sprintf(name,"rho_com_sigma_%3.2f.dat", sigma);
    rho = fopen(name,"w");

    p2=estados1;
    p3=estados2; 

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){p3[i]=p2[i];} */

while(t<tempo and total_ativos[t]!=0){
    //flag
    if(t%2){p2=estados2;
        p3=estados1;
        }
    else{
        p2=estados1;
        p3=estados2;
        };

    aux = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        switch(p2[i]){
            case 0:{ //falta adicionar o estimulo externo
                for(j=0; j<k; j++){
                    if(p2[pos[i][j]]==1 and P[i][j] > myrand){
                        p3[i]=1;
                        aux+=1;
                        break;
                        };
                        p3[i] = 0;
                    };
                break;
                }
            case (estados_maximos-1):{
                p3[i]=0;
                break;
                }

            default:{
                p3[i]=p2[i]+1;
                break;
            }

            } // fim do switch

        }; // fim do for

        t+=1;
        total_ativos[t] = aux;

        }; //fim do while

    //gravar o total de ativos em arquivo    
    for(i = 0; i<tempo+1;i++){
        fprintf(rho,"%d %lf\n",i,(double)total_ativos[i]/n);}
    fclose(rho);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Problema perfeitamente solucionado pelo Isac abaixo. Muito agradecido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro tem a ver com o tamanho dos elementos alocados em *stack* com `int pos[n][k]` e restantes, que passa o limite e gera um *Segmentation Fault*.

Pode tentar configurar o tamanho do *stack* para que as alocações não ultrapassem o limite mas a solução mais comum é alocar dinamicamente com [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) ou no caso do c++ com [`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/). Na alocação dinamica o mesmo limite já não se impõe.

Para confirmar o problema mencionado basta alterar a constante `n`:

```
const int n = 100000; //elementos
```

Para `100` que vê que o *Segmentation Fault* desaparece logo.

Exemplificando a solução alocando com `malloc` para o `int estados1[n]` seria:

```
int *estados1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Já para o caso do vetor `pos` fica mais elaborado pois é um vetor bidimensional:

```
int **pos = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    pos[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k);
}
```

Como aparte, o código que tem não é código C puro, pois tem umas quantas coisas de C++ tais como `#include <iostream>`, `or v==elemento` entre outras. Isto significa que não consegue compilar o código apresentado na pergunta como C mas apenas como C++, e por esse motivo eu deixei os *casts* nos `mallocs` pois eles são obrigatórios em C++. Se o objetivo é C++ então transite e utilize as funcionalidades que este lhe dá que são bem mais simples e diretas.

Comment: Muito obrigado de coração! Eu tenho habilidades em programar em python porém para simulações estou sendo obrigado a trabalhar em C. Que sua ajude volte em dobro de alegrias para você! Abraço!